# Creating a dictionary with unknown key and appending a list value to it?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to be able to loop through all objects in my game and check their self.owner stat.

To do so I do:

```
for ship in game_map._all_ships():
     ....
```

I want to make a dictionary with the key as the players and a list of values of ships:

```
dictionary { 'Player 0' :[ship 1, ship 2], 'Player 1': [ship 1] ... etc}
```

I can retrieve their player with

```
ship.owner
```

But I don't know how to initialize the dictionary with lists without knowing how many players there are or how many ships they have without first running the loop.

Comment: take a look at defaultdict

Comment: It's perfectly fine to start with empty lists/dicts and grow them as you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smoothest approach uses a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) in order to avoid checking for keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)
for ship in game_map._all_ships():
    dic[ship.owner].append(ship)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
# create an empty dictionary
mydictionary = {}
# loop through all ship objects
for ship in game_map._all_ships():
    # check if there's not list yet for the ship owner
    if ship.owner not in mydictionary:
        # if no such list exists yet, create it with an empty list
        mydictionary[ship.owner] = []
    # with the ship owner name as key, extend the list with the new ship
    mydictionary[ship.owner].append(ship)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you require here is [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), a wrapper class around `dict`, which provides all the basic dictionary functionality along with allowing to create empty valued key-value pair.

Pydoc defines it as :

> **class collections.defaultdict([default_factory[, ...]])**
>
> Returns a new dictionary-like object. defaultdict is a subclass of the built-in dict
>   class. It overrides one method and adds one writable instance
>   variable. The remaining functionality is the same as for the dict
>   class and is not documented here.
>
> The first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory
>   attribute; it defaults to None. All remaining arguments are treated
>   the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor, including
>   keyword arguments.

Small example code :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

# create defaultdict containing values of `list` type
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d
=> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})

# assuming we need to add list `l` value to the dictionary with key 'l'
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> for ele in l: 
        d['l'].append(ele)    

>>> d
=> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'l': [1, 2, 3]})
```